# Run a scheduled SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, scheduled-tasks

I have an SQL query that I want to run multiple times a day.
I want it to be run automatically.
Many are saying I should use **Cron Job** using the following code:

`*/4 * * * * wget --spider file.php`

It's actually exactly what I want but I really don't know where to run it in my php code.

Comment: Check here about crontab http://www.pantz.org/software/cron/croninfo.html what it is and how it works.

Comment: It's not run from php code, it is what runs your php code. How to do it depends on what server you have.

Comment: Why don't you use the MySQL Event Scheduler to run your query? Or use `crontab` on the server to run the PHP script directly, instead of going through the webserver.

Comment: Also, it's `Cron Job`, not `Cran Job`. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I need:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
ON SCHEDULE [EVERY interval | AT timestamp]
DO event_content
```

For those who don't know `|` means `OR`

Thank you for the answers guys!

link: [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html)

Comment: Nice solution, I never use it but I certainly will.

Comment: @rand can you show exactly how did you use this statement inside your PHP file? Did you put it inside a msqli class? did you use PDO instead? I'm interested since I find myself in the same situation and I don't understand how to make it work

Answer (score 2):

If you use **Windows** : launch the `Task Scheduler` with this command : `taskschd.msc`.

It is a GUI, so I let you manage it, it is not so complicated.

If you use **Linux/Unix** : you have to use a `cron job`.

In a shell :

```
crontab -e
```

It launches `vim` editor, so inside it write :

```
*/4 * * * * php  /directory/to/your/file.php
```

Or

```
*/4 * * * * wget http://your_server/file.php
```

For more information about crontab, read the links in the comments of your question or google it. ;)

Comment: I think then it's neither, because I need to run an SQL query

Comment: @rand You can create a php file which runs the query or use `mysql -u yourUser -p yourPassword -e 'YourQuery' yourdatabase`. PHP is probably a bit nicer since you can check results, write logs, e.t.c.

Comment: Yeah, I'd prefer a PHP solution, but again I don't know a PHP syntax to run a scheduled "function" or "SQL query"